# Ubercart Module for handling subscriptions?

Tags: ubercart, notifications

Trying to figure out the best UC module to use for this...

Essentially, I'm trying to create a site where users may purchase subscriptions.  There are about 15 different subscriptions a user may purchase.  The first subscription (regardless of which one it is) will sell at $20.  Every additional subscription purchase after that will cost $10.

Not sure which module to use (or if one even exists) to accomplish this.  There appears to be so many contributed modules, and the descriptions "kinda sorta" seem like what I need, but a lot of them sound very similar...

If someone knows a good way to accomplish this, that'd be great...

Answer (score 3):

Look at [UC Recurring](http://drupal.org/project/uc_recurring) module. It should do what you need. The instruction on how to set it up is [here](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/uc_recurring).

Answer (score 2):

Paypal and I think perhaps one or two other gateways have recurring payments APIs that Ubercart can work with. In that setup, Ubercart just initiates a subscription and Paypal takes it from there, and you manage the subscriptions from within Paypal. It's good because I trust Paypal with this sort of thing a little more than Drupal, but its bad because the Paypal interface is terrible and you can't really change Payment amounts once a subscription is initiated (you just have to cancel and re-subscribe).

Answer (score 2):

There is also a **Ubercart Contributed Module** called [Subscriptions](http://www.ubercart.org/project/subscribe)

> uc_subscribe provides a framework for tracking and acting on
>   subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

There was a [session on subscriptions](http://denver2012.drupal.org/program/sessions/recurring-billing-hard-hard-hard) at Drupalcon Denver 2012 (watch the video of the session at the link) specifically on the problems Lullabot encountered setting up [drupalize.me](http://drupalize.me).

Answer (score 0):

The moneyscripts module (unfortunately its not free) worked for me when I built a website for a customer of ours.  I can't remember where I found it but do a search for moneyscripts and there is a really good recurring payments module there.  It operates outside of ubercart which is kind of nasty if you also need ubercart but if subscriptions is all you want its brilliant.